# Move index of a string in string.ascii_lowercase

Tags: python, string

I want to change letters in a string by moving the index by 2 steps:
a --> c, b--> d, c--> e, etc. However, when it gets to the final letters in alphabetical order, I don't know how to make: y --> a and z --> b since it goes out of index when you reach these two letters. Also, I'm sure there's a better way to solve this problem. Thanks!

```
str = "rpylqjyrc"
step = 2
new_str = []

for letter in str:
    if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        index = string.ascii_lowercase.index(letter) + step
        word = string.ascii_lowercase[index]
        new_str.append(word)
    else:
        new_str.append(letter)

print("".join(new_str))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator to loop through `ascii_lowercase`.

```
index = (string.ascii_lowercase.index(letter) + step) % 26
```

But Python already has the built-in method `str.translate` for these kind of string operations.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercases

my_string = "rpylqjyrc"

translation = str.maketrans(lowercases, lowercases[2:] + lowercases[:2])

new_string = my_string.translate(translation)
```

Also, I recommend you abstain from calling your variable `str` as this overshadows the built-in `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for computing a shifted character:

```
def shift_lc( c, shift ):
    new_ord = ord(c) + shift
    return chr( new_ord - (26 if new_ord > ord('z') else 0) )
```

Comment: I like your solution, I recommend you give a usage example as it can be done in a single line with `map` or like this `''.join(shift_lc(c, 2) for c in my_string)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic application of the modulo operator.

You want the index range between `['a', 'z']` always. There are 26 alphabets.
So our new index when we add our step count has to be from `[0, 26] + index of 'a'`.

In order to do this, we can just do `index = (index) % 26`